# Pandas None type when loading data in Chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Greetings data Scientists.

I have written this function to load my data in chunks, it works fine and it gives me a shape of my data but when I try to assign it to a variable so that I can be able to clean my data and work on it it shows that its a none type

```
def show(df):
start = time()

c=0
for chuck in pd.read_csv('../input/{}.csv'.format(df), chunksize=50000):
    if c==0:
        df=chuck
        c+=1
    else:
        df=df.append(chuck, ignore_index=True)
        c+=1
print (c)

print('used {:.2f} s'.format(time()-start))

print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

My data originally has 307511 rows and 212 columns. There are other datasets that I still have to load with millions of rows. My RAM can't handle this amount of data hence I request an assistance on this

I have also tried this way of loading data but I can't get all of my data but a certain portion of it. I want to use my all of my data when I am merging and fitting my data

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/application_train.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10**6, engine='python')
```

This works but I don't get all of my data out of it

```
df = df.get_chunk(300000)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: Is it not this the start in Machine learning? I am confused now

Comment: The fact that you may be building, say, a sorting algorithm to be subsequently used in a spaceship does not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`; for all we know, your question *may* be related to some ML modeling further downstream and may be not, but even if it *is*, the `machine-learning` tag is used for questions specific to machine learning tasks, in which tasks as pure data handling/engineering/formatting etc do not necessarily belong...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me. Now I know what to do next time Thanks a lot. We learn everyday :)

Comment: You are very welcome, and we all indeed learn everyday - keep on! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes works fine with me. I once had the same problem. Try not to put your code in a function and see how it works, a for loop works fine on its own. try this

```
start = time()
data = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('../input/youdataset.csv', chunksize = 50000):
    data.append(chunk)

print(len(data))

df  = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True)

print('used {:.2f}s'.format(time()-start))
print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, @Sazi This works perfectly but now I have to write this for all my datasets that I am loading

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to run the code exactly as it is in your question?

If so, some problems that come to mind:

- Indentation: Every line after "def..." should be indented, if you want it to be part of the function.
- Multiple values in df: You start with it being a filename, but then you change its value in the middle of your loop, so that it would be different when it goes back to the top of the loop.
- Using df as multiple types of values. Creating it once, as an empty list, and appending it iteratively, would seem to better serve your purpose.

Try something like this:

```
def show(file_name):
    start = time()

    c=0
    df = []
    for chuck in pd.read_csv('../input/{}.csv'.format(file_name), chunksize=50000):
        df.append(chuck, ignore_index=True)
        c+=1
    print (c)

    print('used {:.2f} s'.format(time()-start))

    print(df.shape)
    df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the indentation I implemented it correctly. When I try to run your function I get this error I am not sure what's wrong with append.
`TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: Sorry, that `append` shouldn't have that second value, and should conclude with (chuck).

Comment: If you want to make a loop for all your data, that should work.